# solve $y = \frac{A }{\frac{B}{\ln(y/y_0)} - 1} \frac{1}{x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm trying to express y as a function of x, using the following equation :

$$ y = \frac{A }{\frac{B}{\ln(y/y_0)} - 1} \frac{1}{x^2} $$

Can anyone help me ? Thanks !

[Edit]
- I originally attempted to simplify the equation, but by doing so removed an important part of the problem ... sorry !
- @the_candyman : I tried solving this with the syms package in Matlab, which returned "Explicit solution could not be found"
- @Dr. Graubner : all variables are real. A>0, B<0. This is an electrical engineering problem.

Comment: Welcome to SE.Mathematics. Please, add more information. What have you already done?

Comment: can you say something to the variables?

Comment: i think this is impossible in the general case

Comment: So now that you edited it, does this means $y_0 = y(x=0)$?

Comment: @Hamed No, y0 is an arbitrary reference value for y.